# use facebook login feature or not

Tags: login, facebook

I intend implementing facebook login to my web app-and also the traditional registration form.
There are some questions that arise though and are not general but specific to the nature of the app.Let me explain by describing the web app...
It is a booking/appointments app.The user is closing an appointment with his/her name and this name must be shown to the business user for whom the booking is made.
And here is the scenario that might question the option of using facebook login:

1. Many facebook users do not use real names in their account but aliases.Τhe business user of course must know the real name of the user so(for example) can track his clientele.You cannot do that with an alias...

This is one reason I can think of that prevents me using facebook login.
Other reasons might arise in the future.

**What do you think?(given the nature of the app)**

Answer (score 3):

Put a Facebook login. I always use FB logins whenever I can. It's so convenient. I don't want 9 different logins and have to remember which email and password I used. One login for everything will decrease the number of people who forgot their passwords and usernames. And it will make people more likely to create accounts in the first place. Making yet another account is really annoying to people. But when there's a Facebook login available, it only takes a couple of clicks.
As for the real name, just put in another field where they can write their full name. Have a checkbox option that says their facebook name is already their real name so they don't have to input a name. I've seen many other sites that have a facebook login, but still require you to input information, like a new password.

Comment: can you mention an example of a site that has facebook login and still require some info...I want to see it.

Comment: http://www.dogvacay.com is one example:   [extra info required by dogvacay after fb login](http://i.imgur.com/8FSTMkK.png)

Comment: Call me old-fashioned but I *never* use facebook login because I am considerate of who I share my data with. In fact a facebook login will not make me "more likely to create an account". Quite the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

The benefits of using Facebook's login vastly outweigh the downfalls.

First off, you get **Targeted Content** where you can obtain a profile and social graph data in order to target personalized content to the user. This includes information such as name, email, hometown, interests, activities and friends.

Secondly, you just gained access to a **Pre-Validated Email**, essentially preventing the user from supplying you a fabricated email address during the registration process.

But most importantly your user can take advantage of **Account Linking**, and now has one less password to remember.

**86%** of users are bothered by the [signup process](http://www.webhostingbuzz.com/blog/2013/03/21/whos-sharing-what/)

**77%** of users prefer social login.

**92%** of users will leave a site instead of reset a password or username.

**88%** of users have entered in fake data to get past the signup process

And lastly, just ask if "Booger McBoogerson" is their real name and not their Facebook alias. Most people will give you their real name when asked.

Comment: Keep in mind though that **targeted content** is exactly the reason why people might **not** want to login using Facebook.

Comment: @RomanReiner: agreed. make sure to provide other options as well.

Answer (score 1):

> … given the nature of the app …

For the record: You need reliable data from people and your findings say that you can’t rely with certainty on the information provided by Facebook.

**Allow people to edit their information any time before they close an appointment.**

A possible conclusion is that you need to have the traditional registration and let users decide if they want to login using Facebook or not. You can ask for the full name (and other data you need) before asking to register using Facebook or create a username and password. If this doesn't discourage people to register it can certainly help people decide if it's appropriate with this information to involve their Facebook account or not.

Answer (score 0):

I put in both FB and Linkedin logins only and was planning to add the standard username/pass but the sign ups are solid and spam signups are minimal (once I blocked certain countries), so I've stuck with those 2.

Actually, I think the Linkedin signups are higher than the FB signups.

Above the sign up buttons is a message saying 'we never post for you' with a solid explanation linked to it. I like to see that when I use other people's sites.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.mailchimp.com/social-login-buttons-arent-worth-it/

To give you a sum up: Mailchimp found that social media buttons for login were not worth it because remember, when someone goes on your site, they might not remember which portal they used to login (was it email? Or facebook? Oh no, there's google plus too? WHICH ONE?!).

I suggest you choose one and stick with it. That way, users coming back will know what to log into instead of spending time remembering which portal they initially logged into.

Answer (score 0):

Since all answers so far seems to advice on using the Facebook login I would like to weigh in some counter arguments.

- Facebook is *private* and business is *business*. Many people like to keep that separate.
- Users might perceive an app with Facebook login as less *serious/professional/"businessy"* which might shoo away potential customers.
- Users might not trust you or Facebook with *their data*. Especially where clients are involved.

Since your app is a business app I would advise against it. Consider using similar login services from a more work related site like LinkedIn and in either case make sure you can also log in using classic registration.

Comment: I must say you have a point....one potential workaround is to have facebook login for regular users and a classic registration form for business users...What do you think about that?

Answer (score -1):

I say put it in there. I heard a lot of feedback from not that savvy people that they are afraid to log in through Facebook because they think their data is getting exposed. I say that's a precaution that will disappear even if not that savvy people. It is to become a standard, because if offers convenience. Make it convenient for a user is our job, so at list give them an option but not necessarily force it.

Comment: Actually login through facebook **will** expose (some of) your data: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions